# Custom logic during Save/Update if a Model implements a specific interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If all my Entity Framework Models implement certain interfaces, is it possible for me to add logic to my Save method such that, if the Model being save implements a specific interface, perform some custom logic?

Example, say I have an interface like:

```
public interface IDateUpdated
{
    //DateUpdated
}
```

So now when I am saving/updating an Entity, if the Model implements IDateUpdated, then it should do:

```
someEntity.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
```

Is this possible?

(I am using EF 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `SaveChanges` in your `DbContext`. Assuming you don't have too many interfaces you could just put the code right there.

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries();

    if (changeSet != null) {
        foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(x => x.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged)) {
            // Implements interface?
            if (entry.Entity is IDateUpdated) {
                ((IDateUpdated)entry.Entity).DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you save the entity, you can just check if it implements the interface before you perform the custom logic.

```
if (someEntity is IDateUpdated)
{
    someEntity.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
}
```